# How can I control decimals in Ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have this code to get some density Plots, and the ticks on the x-axis has two decimals but at zero appears only one `0.`. How can I make all ticks consistent such that it appears as `0.0` please?
here is the code: first part I creat specific ticks form

```
<< MaTeX`
TX[XZ_, YZ_] := Piecewise[{{XZ/YZ, XZ >= YZ}, {1, XZ < YZ}}]
s[lbls_, j_, tl_] := 
  Table[{j i, If[lbls, j i, ""], {0, -tl}, Black}, {i, -10^2, 10^2}];
p[j_, ts_, ns_] := 
 Table[{(j (i))/ns, "", {0, -ts}, Black}, {i, -10^2, 10^2}]; 
ticks[lbls_, j_, tl_, ts_, ns_] := 
 ArrayFlatten[{{s[lbls, j, tl]}, {p[j, ts, ns]}}];
Tx[lbls_ : True, MSx_, Msz_, Ssz_, nSS_, XZ_, YZ_] := 
  ticks[lbls, MSx, Msz TX[XZ, YZ], Ssz TX[XZ, YZ], nSS];
```

and here is the density plot

```
fgt = Table[{x, y, Cos[10 x y]^2}, {x, -0.2, 0.2, 0.01}, {y, 0.0001, 
    5.0001, 0.1}];
With[{XZ = 100, YZ = 160, sx = 0.2, sy = 1, m = 1.3}, 
 ListDensityPlot[Flatten[fgt, 1], 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, f},  Abs[y + 1] - Abs[x] > 0 ], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 0.2}, {0, 5}, All}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0.7, 1], 
       RGBColor[0, 0.7, 1, 1], RGBColor[1, 1, 0, 0], 
       RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0, 1], RGBColor[0.6, 0, 0, 1]}, #] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", Black, 
    FontSize -> 14}, 
  FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, Magnification -> m] &) /@ {"X", "Y"}, 
  Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Automatic -> {XZ, YZ}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Tx[sy, 0.04, 0.02, 2 sy, YZ, XZ], 
     Tx[False, sy, 0.04, 0.02, 2 sy, YZ, XZ]}, {Tx[sx, 0.04, 0.02, 2 ,
       XZ, YZ], Tx[False, sx, 0.04, 0.02, 2 , XZ, YZ]}}, 
  PlotTheme -> {"mysty", 0.007, 0.007, YZ, XZ}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> True]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to go could be to use `NumberForm`, e.g. in you definition of `s`:

```
s[lbls_, j_, tl_] := Table[{j i, If[lbls, NumberForm[j i, {2, 1}], ""], {0, -tl}, Black}, {i, -10^2, 10^2}];
```

This changes in your code also thy y-axis ticks, but if you don't want that you can always use two different ticks functions.

[image]